# In GCViewer Heap area is not divided into two areas, new and old

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory

I analyzed a GClog with GCViewer and it gave this result.
[GCViewer-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq3iQ.jpg)

I'm newby to GCViewer.

In my recognition, result is supposed to be divided into two areas, meaning new and old.
But there is no area like that, but only red area.
At View Configuration, "Total Heap" is not checked. "Tenured Generation" and "Young Generation" is checked. How can I make this result including new and old area?

This makes me difficult analyzing memory situation. Can anyone give me advices?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will help,
It is more of a configuration issue than a problem.

Check the tool report [here](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tools/gcviewer/)

Also, it would be easier if you share your JAVA versions. (JDK)
Because it doesn't seem like you are using a generational GC.

More like a Parallel GC. So It is probably JAVA 8.
I think you use the default GC. You should change it with `-XX:+UseG1GC`

Why I am saying that?? Because you don't have anything like:

```
Tenured Heap (usage/max): ???M (???%) / ???M

Young Heap (usage/max): ???M (???%) / ???M
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue.
GCViewer has problems with G1 logs.
GCViewer developers developer site on github:

> Supported verbose:gc formats are: ...

> some support for OpenJDK 9 / 10 unified logging format -Xlog:gc:, the following configurations will work
>
> - ```
>      -Xlog:gc:file="path-to-file" (uses defaults)
>   ```
> - ```
>      -Xlog:gc=info:file="path-to-file":tags,uptime,level (minimum configuration needed)
>   ```
> - ```
>      -Xlog:gc*=trace:file="path-to-file":tags,time,uptime,level (maximum configuration supported, additional tags ok, but ignored; additional decorations will break parsing)
>   ```

I use OpenJDK 11 with G1.
With setting "-Xlog:gc*=trace" You see all GCViewer lines and areas but missing:

- tenured generation
- used tenured heap
- initial mark level

Event details tab content is very good.

If you are interested, see *imp/DataReaderUnifiedJvmLogging.java* filter in GCViever sources for information on gc log lines taken in account.

[Reference for G1GC tuning with advices for log config in problem situations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector-tuning.html#GUID-90E30ACA-8040-432E-B3A0-1E0440AB556A)

[Reference for the Java unified logging framework usage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5)